# Stopped preview when capture in Camera2API

Tags: android-camera2

When I capture the image based on Camera2, the camera preview stopped for a little while.
Why preview stopped? Is there any idea? please..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I used the Camera2 API the first time. The problem was that I instanciated a new CaptureSession to capture the image. I fixed this by submitting the capture request to the same CaptureSession instance that created the preview and not to a new one.

Please note that you need to configure the CaptureSession object with all the surfaces that will be used by the following requests.